# Solution for the ODE $y'=xy$ using as arbitrary constant.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Not sure if I'm missing something or if its the formatting of Web Assign marking it wrong:

**Work done**

1) *Given the differential equation, y'=xy, I swapped out y' with dy/dx so I could do the isolation of x and y*: ***y'=xy => dy/dx = xy***

2) *Completed the isolation of x and y by multiplying by dx and 1/y on both sides* ***(1/y)(dx)(dy/dx)=(x)(y)(dx)(1/y) => (1/y)(dy)=x(dx)***

3) *Integrated both sides* ***integration resulted in ln|y|=x+c, where c is some constant***

*Solved for y by using e to cancel out ln|y|**e^ln|y|=e^x+c =>y=(e^x)(e^c)**

As for the answer, since I implied from the instructions that K was to be the arbitrary constant, I swapped out c for K and submitted that **y=(e^x)(e^K)**, but it was marked as wrong. I'm really confused, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note:  $\int xdx = x^2/2 + c$.

Comment: Changing to (e^(x^2)/2)) still comes back as wrong

Comment: (e^(x^2)/2)) is $$\frac{e^{x^2}}{2} \neq e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Looks like you got it straightened out *via* UserX and his answer!

Answer (score 1):

3rd step;

$$\int \frac{1}{y} \mathrm{d}y = \int x \mathrm{d}x \iff \ln(|y|)=\frac{x^2}{2}+k \iff y=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}+k}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} e^k=k e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!! Professor taught it a different way in the lecture by keeping them separate, but I guess he should've noted that WA would want it like that.

Comment: Also, a faster way is to go $$\int \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}{y} \mathrm{d}x= \int x \mathrm{d}x$$(Yea, only two steps less, but getting used to functions and their derivatives inside integrals is quite usefull)

Answer (score 0):

Rigorous way:

If
$$
y'(x)=xy(x),
$$
then 
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}y'(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}xy(x),
$$
or
$$
\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}y(x)\right)'=\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}y'(x)-\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}xy(x)=0,
$$
which means that there exists a constant $k$ such that
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}y(x)=k,
$$
or
$$
y(x)=k\,\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}.
$$